# QGIS: additional description in legend

Tags: qgis, symbology

[image]In ArcMap there is the possibility to have a symbol, the symbol description or layer name and an additional description in your legend

Layer Properties --> Symbology --> Fetaures: Single symbol --> Description (Additional description appearing next to the symbol in your map’s legend)

Is there any way to do this in QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you have more than one symbol (e.g. rule based symbology / categorized symbology) - i.e. as soon as it gets important to be able to distinguish different features based on their symbology - there is a label next to each symbol in the legend with a configurable description.

[image: Layer > Style configuration > Rule Based > Label Editing]

[image: Legend with description labels]

Comment: Thanks for your help.
But I need the description in the legend.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @MatthiasKuhn's answer, you can also add a *Description* to each symbol if it is considered too long or if you wanted to add additional details but not overcrowd the legend (i.e. this won't be shown in the legend):

[image: Description]

Comment: Thanks for your help.
But I need the description in the legend.

Comment: @SylLor - Not sure QGIS can do exactly what you could do in ArcMap but in the **Label** textbox, you could as a workaround enter a name and insert a dozen _spaces_ and then enter a description. So that in the end, there's a big gap in between similar to in your image.